# Creating CSV in C#, missing commas and putting each value on new line

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ado.net

I'm having an issue creating a csv file from a database.

Basically what is happening is the each value is being added on it's own line without a comma.

it should be looking like this:

```
ColumnValue1, ColumnValue2, ColumnValue3, ColumnValue4
ColumnValue1, ColumnValue2, ColumnValue3, ColumnValue4
```

but i am getting this:

```
ColumnValue1
ColumnValue2
ColumnValue3
ColumnValue4
ColumnValue1
ColumnValue2
ColumnValue3
ColumnValue4
```

**Update:** the values being entered are DateTime (11/17/2014 12:00:00:000) Int, Int and String

Here is an example of my code:

```
private string GenerateCSV(string fileLocation)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(fileLocation, "filename.csv");
    var csvList = new List<String>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        using (IDbCommand command = new SqlCommand("Example command") { CommandTimeout = 0  })
        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    csvList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_Log.Error("{0}", e);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < csvList.Count; index++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", csvList[index]));
    }
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: I see not reasons why the code you've posted will output more than one item per row. Consider careful debugging if you can't read the code.

Comment: Note that you simply should use existing CSV reader/writer instead of inventing your own (unless it is homework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to `for (int index = 0; index < csvList.Count; index++)` loop, `csvList` contains values of fields from all records that `reader` had gone through - as separate items. Then you call `string.Join` which expects an array of strings as second parameter, but is content to take `csvList[index]` string making it into a string array with a single item. Hence, there is nothing to join with "," here, and `csvList[index]` is simply `AppendLine`ed to `StringBuilder`.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  List<string> fields = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
  {
    fields.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[i]));
  }
  csvList.Add(string.Join(",", fields.ToArray());
}

for (int index = 0; index < csvList.Count; index++)
{
  sb.AppendLine(csvList[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for (int index = 0; index < csvList.Count; index++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", csvList[index]));
    }
```

use

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", csvList));
```